# Why does this modulo bit operation work?

Tags: math, bit-manipulation

i found out, that you can do modulo using this :

```
x % m == (x + x / m) & m
```

but i cannot understand why its working...

like for 8 % 7 == (8 + 8 / 7) & 7, this is

```
x = 8 =          0001 0000
x / 7 = 1 =      1000 0000
x + x / 7 = 9 =  1001 0000
9 & 7 =          1001 0000 & 1110 0000 = 1000 0000 = 1
```

Comment: Your bits are backwards.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't your example already showing how it's working?

Comment: sory, i reversed the bit order (i used another custom:)... i see it working, but i dont understand why

Comment: So you're asking for a mathematical proof?

Comment: yup, for a mathematical explanation, why this works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
N = 7k + m, m<7
N/7 = k
N + N/7 = 8k + m
(N + N/7) & 7 = (8k + m) & 7
              = m & 7
              = m
```

It works for any 2<sup>n</sup>-1 number, not just 7.

Comment: how did (8k + m) & 7 became m & 7, and how did m & 7 became m ?

Comment: I think it's because 7 is just `0111`, so if you `&` with any bits higher than those, it'd just become 0 anyway

Comment: @PeterLapisu, @MysticXG, yes, 8k ends in `000`, and m<8 so m will be entirely in the last three bits, so (8k+m)&7 = m&7. And since 7 is `111` and m is in the last three bits, m&7 = m.